# Using variable as function argument in r

Tags: r, variables, arguments

I want to control a linear regression model with a specific variable. If i assign variable "c" as 0, i want to estimate the model:

```
lm(y ~ x)    # model with intercept
```

and if i assign variable "c" as 1 i want to estimate:

```
lm(y ~ x - 1) # model without intercept
```

I tried the code below

```
c <- 1
lm(y ~ x - c)
```

but it didn't work. c is 1 but in lm function i can't use this variable for argument. How can i assign and use a variable to add intercept and remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula objects don’t evaluate their arguments (otherwise they fundamentally wouldn’t work). So you need to find a way of interpolating an *evaluated* value into the unevaluated formula expression.

Like all problems of computer science, this can be solved by one more layer of indirection.

Create an unevaluated expression that *creates* your formula, and evaluate it after interpolating the variable:

```
formula = eval(bquote(y ~ x - .(c)))
lm(formula)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that with a simple variable. Rather than conditionally setting the value of `a`, you can conditionally remove the intercept. Something like

```
myformula <- y~x
if(TRUE) {
  myformula <- update(myformula, ~.-1)
}
myformula
# y ~ x - 1
```